# Order of operations in statistics

Tags: order-statistics

How should I understand P(a|b,c)?  Is it P() of a given b and c, or P() of a given b, and then c?  How can I flip the order inside the brackets?  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Everything to the *left* of the $\mid$ is the event whose *conditional* probability is being talked about; everything to the right of the $\mid$ 
is the *conditioning* event, the one that we assume has occurred. Commas
generally mean intersection. Thus, $P(A\mid B, C)$  is the same
as $P(A\mid B\cap C)$ or $P(A\mid (B\cap C))$, the *conditional* probability of the event $A$
*conditioned* on the occurrence of the event $B\cap C$ or
$(B\cap C)$ depending on how nitpicky you are about parentheses.

In fact, it is best to be nitpicky about parentheses when one is
starting to learn the subject (or when one is teaching the subject
to beginners) because many beginners think of 
$P(A \mid B \cap C)$ as meaning "the probability that
both the events (i) $A$ given $B$, and (ii) $C$, have occurred."
There is **no event** called "$A$ given $B$" that we can intersect
with $C$; there is only the event $A$,
and we can talk of the *unconditional* probability that $A$ occurred,
or of the conditional probability that $A$ occurred. Here, we
are considering the *conditional* probability of $A$, and the
*condition***ing**  event in this instance is $B\cap C$. 
That vertical bar
is a bright shining line that separates the conditioned event from
the conditioning event.

Comment: if I have this relationship: b--->a--->c, how can I calculate P(a|b,c)?

Comment: @CaTx That is a separate question and should be asked separately.

Answer (score 7):

## Order doesn't matter

Order doesn't matter in this setting, so there isn't any order of operations to worry about.  Explicitly:

$$P(a \mid b, c) = P(a \mid c, b)$$

This is because the AND logical concept doesn't depend on order.  Consider the statement "It is Wednesday AND I am a student". This is an equivalent logical statement to "I am a student AND it is Wednesday"

Let's say $A$ represents whether or not I am currently in the library.  Then $P(A \mid \text{student AND Wednesday})$ is intuitive no different than $P(A \mid \text{wednesday AND student})$

Comment: OK, so things are being separate by the conditional sign, as Dilip Sawarte points out.

Comment: Note that if you replace your `|` in the Latex code with `\mid`, then there is wider spacing around the symbol, and this makes it clearer what the correct order is (for the same reason why it is better to write `2 + 3*5` than `2+3 * 5`).